# Why page not redirecting in AngularJS+Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express, angular-routing

I am making an demo site with angular express seed by Brian Ford (thanks a lot), but after edit a post it does not redirecting to listing url. edit operation doing fine just not redirecting to listing page after hit the submit button . In chrome it is showing Pending in status that never ends... my codes are as bellow:

**Angular controller**

```
function EditPostCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $http.get('/api/posts/details/' + $routeParams.id).
        success(function(data) {
           $scope.form = data.post;
        });

    $scope.editPost = function () {
        $http.post('/api/posts/edit/' + $routeParams.id, $scope.form).
            success(function(data) {
                $location.path('/posts');
            });
    };
};
```

**Express App**

```
app.post('/api/posts/edit/:id',api.adminLoginCheck,api.editPost);
```

**Api.js**

```
exports.editPost = function (req, res,next) {
    console.log("editPost");

    var id = req.params.id;
    req.body.slug = req.body.title.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
    delete req.body._id;
    myMongoDb.update({slug:id},'posts',req.body, function(error,results){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.json(false);
        }else{
            res.json(true);
        }

    });
};
```

What i am doing wrong? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe you can add an error handler when you use $http in angularjs. This way you know if something went wrong. I also wonder if `res.json(boolean)` is valid.

Comment: json `res.json(boolean)` is valid. i solved the problem yesterday. it was a problem in my mongoDB wrapper class. many thanks to reply